# polynomial evaluation time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, polynomials

I was going through this link :
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/horners-method-polynomial-evaluation/

Here it says that the time complexity using normal method is O(n^2).But I wonder how?Here is my analysis about this:

Suppose we have an equation like:2x^2 + x + 1
Here the for loop will be executed 3 times i.e.(order+1)times

```
    for(int i = order ; i>=0 ; i++){
         result = result + (mat[i] * coefficient^i);
    }
```

So according to this ,the time complexity should be O(n+1) i.e. O(n).Why does it say that its O(n^2)?I'm getting a little lost here.Even a hint would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The form you show is often called [Horner's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method#Description_of_the_algorithm). It is linear in the sense that the number of elementary operations (additions, multiplications) is *O(n)*, where *n* is the highest coefficient.

---

Incidentally, your code above seems to contain a mistake. It probably should be

```
for(int i = order ; i>=0 ; i--){
```

(the original is an infinited loop). Otherwise, it can be considered an implementation of Horner.

Comment: So the example that I have taken above.Is this the actual Horner's rule?

Comment: @Reckoner Basically yes, but you seem to have a minor bug. See update.

Answer (score 2):

Well it might not be so obvious but some *primitive* operations have different time complexity. Computer is very fast in computing the result of `+` operation, `*` - is slower, `%` - is even more slower. These operations are evaluated on hardware so they take constant number of processor ticks.

But `^` operation is not so simple. `coefficient^i` complexity is not O(1)/constant. Trivial way to calculate the result is to multiply the `coefficient` `i` number of times. This will be done in O(`i`) time. Another way is to use binary exponentiation method that gives faster O(log(`i`)) time.

> Why does it say that its O(n^2)?

You have `n` members in polynomial, you spend O(`n`) time to calculate the result of the exponentiation operation for each of them. That is why it is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 1):

The link suggests that a naive way to evaluate `coefficient^i` would be multiplying `coefficient` `i` times. That is O(i). Repeating this for all exponents from `0` to `n` would be `O(n^2)`

> A naive way to evaluate a polynomial is to one by one evaluate all terms. First calculate x^n, multiply the value with cn, repeat the same steps for other terms and return the sum. Time complexity of this approach is O(n^2) if we use a simple loop for evaluation of x^n.

It also claims that if you use a better algorithm to compute `coefficient^i`, say, exponentiation by squaring, that has O(log n) complexity, it would have a lower total complexity (O(n log n)), but Horner's method would be even better than that.

Comment: As per me,you are correct.The time complexity of calculating power operation will be O(n) if we use divide and conquer.So the overall complexity for the above code will be O(n^2).But then why does it say here that the direct method also has a complexity of O(n).Check this link(Section algebraic functions)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations